# spring MVC how to convert String to TimeStamp automatically in form bean

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

My APP will send a String time parameter to background, like "13/03/2014", if I used TimeStamp in form bean, My ajax request will raise a 400 error, if I used String in form bean, the request will raise smoothly, but I should convert this parameter into TimeStamp, it is not good I think, So I want to know if there is a converter or configuration for such situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use [WebDataBinder.registerCustomEditor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor-java.lang.Class-java.beans.PropertyEditor-) method within `@InitBinder` method.

Here is [an example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-initbinder).